# How can I audit su access through pam.d in RHEL 7

Tags: security, sudo, redhat-enterprise-linux, authentication, pam

I am a system auditor with very limited knowledge of Linux OS. I am currently auditing a RHEL 7 server and found out that a group of users are authenticating through LDAP and using 'su' through PAM. I'd like to know the interpretation of the following file content and where can I view their access logs.

```
etc/pam.d/su

#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient  pam_rootok.so
auth           [success=2 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user notingroup bdbadmin
auth           required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow onerr=fail file=/etc/security/su-bdbadmin-access
auth           required pam_wheel.so use_uid group=bdbadmin
auth           [success=2 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so use_uid user notingroup wheel
auth           required pam_listfile.so item=user sense=allow onerr=fail file=/etc/security/su-wheel-access
auth           required pam_wheel.so use_uid group=wheel

"# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
"#auth      sufficient  pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
"# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
"#auth      required    pam_wheel.so use_uid

auth        substack    system-auth
auth        include     postlogin
account     sufficient  pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account     include     system-auth
password    include     system-auth
session     include     system-auth
session     include     postlogin
session     optional    pam_xauth.so
```

As per my understanding, the users in group bdbadmin are allowed to su access but I don't know where to look for a sudoers list or their access logs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to *StackExchange*, and in particular to *SuperUser*.

1. The access log is located in */var/log/auth.log*, and of course it can only be viewed by *root*.
2. The command to list all members of a given group is *members*, if it is installed in your machine (it is not by default),

   ```
   members sudo
   ```

   or you can directly parse the */etc/group* file which contains the relevant information,

   ```
   grep /etc/group sudo
   ```

   and you can double-check that with

   ```
   group UserName
   ```

to see all groups *UserName* belongs to.

3. As for *PAM* and the file *su*, you should know that by default *PAM* uses a configuration file located in */etc/pam.conf* **unless** the directory */etc/pam.d/* is not empty (your case), in which case the directory content has higher precedence. The syntax of the entries is best learned by referencing the manual [here](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration.html); this Web page *first* discusses the syntax of the */etc/pam.conf* file, then that of the */etc/pam.d/* directory, which is marginally different (and now you see why I had to mention the difference above).

If you have a specific question about the content of the ruleset in *su* above, which after reading the Manual appears quite transparent to me, I will be happy to answer it, if I can.